# How to use a class as a parameter in java?

Tags: java, class, parameter-passing

I,m making a library that can restart any class that calls it's method. It just needs the class to build the command off of. Here's what I have so far:

```
public static void restart(Class a) {
        final String javaBin = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "java";
        try {
            File currentJar = new File(a.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
            /* is it a jar file? */
            if(!currentJar.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
                return;
            }
            /* Build command: java -jar application.jar */
            final ArrayList<String> command = new ArrayList<>(5);
            command.add(javaBin);
            command.add("-jar");
            command.add(currentJar.getPath());
            final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            builder.start();
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(a.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
```

The problem is that variable 'a' is not being recognized as a parameter. Can anybody help?

Comment: _restart any class_ What do you mean?

Comment: So first, do you run into any errors?  Is there some undesirable behavior?  What about this code is...wrong?  You'll need to elaborate, as while one *could* slap this into an IDE, it'd be better if you were up front about the errors/difficulties you were running into.

Comment: Not sure what exactly do u want to do. But if u are taking an input of type Class and then u want to call some method on it, then u need to use reflection.

Comment: In case you trying to reload the class.. you need to write a custom classloader and then load the class through it.. but I don't get the point here is why do you need to do it ?

Comment: and it does a `System.exit(0);`

Comment: I mean restart the application. The method needs to know the main class that the program is running off of.

Answer (score 2):

See below code snippet

```
public class Test {



public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test test = new Test();
    check(test.getClass());
}

public static void check(Class<?> a){
    System.out.println(a);  
}
}
```

Comment: can you explain your answer plz? how is it related to the question?

Comment: @KickButtowski What he is saying, is how are you passing your class in? The important part is that you are passing a class and not an object. I don't see much problem with your code other than you not using generics... I would look at the caller and ensure a class is being properly passed in. I believe that is what Sasikumar M is asking. Sasikumar, could you clarify your answer a bit?

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. I want the parameter to be able to use the .class method.